# Display UILabel on Camera view

Tags: ios

i want open the Camera view and display a `UILabel` on that view with some title and user can not take Photo on that view so no take photo in cameraview

[image]

Any Idea How can i Do this Please.....

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

`[imagePickerController setCameraOverlayView:myView]`

This will allow you to place a view over the camera screen, when you launch it from a `UIImagePickerController`.

Here is the relevent documentation: [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView)

As an aside, you're description of exactly what you want to achieve here isn't so clear. Be aware that if you're directing your user through the standard interface to the camera, and then blocking that, your app may not be accepted by the App Store.